# How to show interstatial admob without button click i tried everything here is my code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

How can I display the interstitial ad when a certain variable in another script which I know how to call when it reaches 3 I need the ad to be displayed?

**Example**

`if(DeathCOunter.deathcount==3){Display_Interstatail};`

But it's not working any help it only works on button click although on button click calls the same `Display_Interstatail();` function

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class InterstaialAd: MonoBehaviour
{
    //private string App_Id = "ca-app-pub-4173360052779175~2584038106";   For real

    private InterstitialAd interstatialAd;

    void Start()
    {
        //  MobileAds.Initialize(App_Id);   this when you publish your app not for testing
        RequestInterstatial();
    }

    void RequestInterstatial()
    {
        string Interstatial_Id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        interstatialAd = new InterstitialAd(Interstatial_Id);

        //not FOR TESTING  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        //for testing
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        interstatialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        //same for testing or no testing
    }

    public void Display_Interstatial()
    {
        if (interstatialAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstatialAd.Show();
        }
    } 

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    { 
            Display_Interstatial();  
    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        RequestInterstatial();
    }

    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    { 
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
    }
}
```

Comment: no expert but ... are the methods like `HandleOnAdLoaded` called by anything? Do you maybe need to add them as callback to some events first? before being able to show an add you would need to request it right?

Comment: pretty unclear to me... I will make a guess: Invoke an event and subscribe in your other script? Let me know if you need some help and I will post a solution

Comment: Hi logonation, nice question! A good way of getting more responses is to try and format your question and use some time with spell checking, punctuation, questionmarks and using paragraphs to make it more readable.